# How to check and uncheck a checkbox field by boolean value?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to update my Users table, and activate or  deactivate a user. But i have problem in that.

I am trying to get a boolean value from Access database into checkbox or radio button. I can't do it. I want if the boolean value is 1 the checkbox should be checked if it's 0 the checkbox should be unchecked.

The same problem for User role I want to display it's current role if necessary update it by selecting Admin or User

Then if I check, it should register 1 or true to the database if unchecked register 0 to database.

Here is my code:

```
// PHP
include_once("../dbConnection.php");
// here i get a user by it's ID to update
$userId = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE User_ID = $userId ; ";
$result = $pdo->query($sql);

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password']);
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $role = $_POST['role'];
   $isActive = $_POST['isActive'];

   $editSql = "UPDATE Users 
               SET Login='$username', Password='$password', Email='$email', Type='$role', UserActive='$isActive'
               WHERE User_ID=$userId;";

   if ($pdo->query($editSql)) {
      echo "Record successfully registered ! <br />";
      header('location: ../index.php');
   } else {
      echo "Could not register ! <br>";
   }
}

foreach ($result->fetchAll() as $row) {
}
```

```
//MY FORM
<form action="" class="container" method="POST">
   <h3 class="text-center mt-0 mb-3">Updating User ! </h3>
   <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <label class="form-label">Username </label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="<?= $row['Login'] ?>" required autofocus>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <label class="form-label" for="">Password </label>
         <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="<?= $row['Password'] ?>" required>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <label class="form-label" for="">Email Address </label>
         <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="<?= $row['Email'] ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <label class="form-label" for="">Select User Type </label>
         <select name="role" class="form-select" required>
            <!-- <option>Choose a Role</option> -->

            <option name="user" value="<?= $row['Type'] ?>" required>User</option>
            <option name="user" value="2" required>User</option>
            <option name="admin" value="1">Admin</option>

         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <label class="form-label" for="">Is Active </label> <br>
         <?php if ($row['UserActive'] == 1) { ?>

            YES: <input type="checkbox" name="isActive" value="1" checked>
         <?php } else { ?>

            NO: <input type="checkbox" name="isActive" value="0">
         <?php } ?>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2" name="update"> Update ! </button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `YES: <input type="checkbox" name="isActive" value="1"<?= $row['UserActive'] == 1 ? ' checked' : ''?>>`

Comment: You should not have two different values... THat would make 4 different possibilities

Comment: _Side note:_ The `<option>` tag doesn't support `name` attributes. It also wouldn't make any sense if they did.

Comment: Thank you so much #mplungjan. You really helped me

Comment: [Your code is open to SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work).